# Posting XML string to WebAPI through Swagger

Tags: asp.net-web-api, swagger, web-api-testing

I have a web api method like this below "ProcessFeed". 
I am using Swagger API to test this service.

The input Data needs to be a big **XML string**. The problem is where there is a **double quote (")** in the string, it is not working.

How can resolve this.

I tried making the method like this too - `ProcessFeed(string data)`

Code

```
public class InputDataModel
        {
            public string Data { get; set; }
        }

        public HttpResponseMessage ProcessFeed(InputDataModel inputDataModel)
        {
            var response = _processorCore.ProcessFeed(inputDataModel.Data);

        }
```

Swagger

```
curl -X POST --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'Accept: application/json' -d '{ \ 
   "Data":  \ 
 "<Date>"2013-02-05"</Date> \ 
 <Time>19:32:33.407</Time>" \ 
 }' 'http://localhost:50545/processfeed'
```

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is in the headers. You need to pass the Content-Type as application/xml